# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18')

Tags: javascript, android, android-resources, react-native

First of, I've look through and tried various resource not found posts but still have not found a working fix for these errors that I'm not sure why are present, given that the last time I launched the app, it built fine.

[image]

Error:(16, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_disabled_color_18').

Error:(9, 30) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18').

Here's what the gradle looks like

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.moveapps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

More core to the issue is that I don't quite understand the problem here, so if anyone can point to where I can read more about this type of issues, I'd love to learn the reasoning behind the fixes.

Cheers,

Edit: Adding Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "moveapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"test": "jest"
 },
"dependencies": {
"async": "^2.4.0",
"firebase": "^3.9.0",
"images": "^3.0.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.18.1",
"react": "15.4.1",
"react-native": "^0.41.2",
"react-native-app-intro": "^1.1.5",
"react-native-apple-healthkit-rn0.40": "^0.2.1-2",
"react-native-chart": "git+https://git@github.com/robcalcroft/react-native-chart.git",
"react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
"react-native-confetti": "0.0.4",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.5.0",
"react-native-fcm": "^6.2.3",
"react-native-firestack": "^2.3.9",
"react-native-google-fit": "^0.2.0",
"react-native-modal-picker": "0.0.16",
"react-native-progress": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-router-flux": "3.37.0",
"react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.2",
"react-native-search-bar": "^3.0.0",
"react-native-searchbar": "^1.10.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.2",
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-persist": "^4.7.1",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"tipsi-stripe": "^3.7.0",
"uuid": "^3.0.1"
  },
 "devDependencies": {
 "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
 "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
 "eslint-config-rallycoding": "^3.2.0",
 "jest": "18.1.0",
 "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
 }
}
```

Comment: Are these images or colors that You set up ?

Comment: Seems like these have changed, or been deleted, but it's just a guess

Comment: add your package.json please

Comment: @NeoVe no, i didnt touch these files.

Comment: is  the problem fixed?

Comment: @MohamedKhalil no sorry I was editing the format when pasting the json file on here

Comment: why you changed the compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion?

Comment: @MohamedKhalil because when i launch android studio, the app won't compile unless i upgrade to 25. and I read somewhere that those two should be the same version so i changed the build tool version to 25 as well. But regardless I played around with the various versions to see if it resolves the missing files...and it didn't work :/ thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: did you installed the sdk version?

Comment: @MohamedKhalil yes, i had both 25.0.0 and 23.0.1 installed

Answer (score 0):

generally this error happen when you don't have the SDK build tools with same version installed so you need to install buildToolsVersion '25.0.0' but based on your `package.json` dependencies you need to change your `android/app/build.gradle`  to be like this

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.moveapps"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

and `android/build.gradle` to be like this

```
buildscript {

  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' // this is the correct version for build tool

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    //        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
   }
}
```

**also it is not recommended to update react native android project throw android studio as it will case errors**

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, I tried this previous and the gradle can't sync as an error that says:   Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.1) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
<a href="fix.build.tools.version">Update Build Tools version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:/Users/kevmc/RNWS/MoveBetter/android/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: so I downgraded to the set up you suggested and then gradle as well to 2.2.3. Doing this seem to hint that there maybe some conflicts between my google services dependencies, so I'm going to investigate that...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, following @mohamed Kahlil's suggestion, I downgraded the build tool version back down to from 25 to 23.0.1. As well the compileSDK to 23 from 25. This however resulted in other dependencies errors between the google services.

First I forced all the google play services and firebase versions that I found were dependencies in the libraries I was using (fcm etc.) to 10.0.1 but it still produced conflicting errors. It was only until I found this medium post:

https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f

That suggested going through all the gradle settings, where I found that the conflicts were in play-services-maps, play-services-wallet, and play-services-identity (even though I didn't actually utilize this). Once I forced the compile versions of these three, the app built without any issues.

So thank you Mohamed for helping me get back in the right direction!

Here's my sample code that I added

```
` android {
   -    compileSdkVersion 25
   -    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
   +    compileSdkVersion 23
   +    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.moveapps"
         minSdkVersion 16
  -        targetSdkVersion 23
  +        targetSdkVersion 22
         multiDexEnabled true
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.1.0"
   @@ -149,20 +149,70 @@ repositories {

  dependencies {
     compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
 -    compile project(':react-native-google-fit')
     compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
 -    compile project(':react-native-fcm')
-    compile project(':react-native-firestack')
+
+    compile(project(':react-native-google-fit')){
+        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-auth'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-fitness'
+    }
+
+    compile(project(':react-native-fcm')){
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
+    }
+
+    compile(project(':react-native-firestack')){
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-core'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-auth'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-analytics'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-storage'
+
+        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
+        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
+    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+
     compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1') {
         force = true;
     }
     compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1') {
         force = true;
     }
-    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1') {
+
+    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1') {
         force = true;
     }
-    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1') {
+    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:10.0.1') {
+        force = true;
+    }
+    compile('com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1') {
         force = true;
     }`
```